# how to optimize jquery ajax chat?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

I am trying to build my own jquery ajax chat and it's realtime notification when message comes like facebook. the plan is to calling ajax request in every 5 second  and finaly my plan is is working fine as my expectation.
but I get problem with my aplication performance after sending message more than 5 time. and the browser become very slow when user input message in input box.
at least am doing following way:

```
//function to updating html element when new message comes (DOM operation)
function refresh_messanger(){

                $(".dialogdiv").remove();
                var y=get_update_message_in_messanger();

                for(var i=0; i<= y.length-1; i++){
                var message=y[i].message_content;
                var message_date=y[i].message_date;
                var src="";
                if(y[i].photo_profile=='{{session("session_photo_profile")}}'){
                    src="{{url('uploads/image').'/'.session('session_login')['app_user_id'].'/'.session('session_photo_profile')}}";
                }else{
                    src="{{url('uploads/image')}}/"+y[i].message_from+'/'+y[i].photo_profile;
                }
                var message_class="";
                if(i==0){
                    message_class="text-bold"
                }else{
                    message_class="text";
                }
                var messagehtml=['<div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">',
                            '<div class="user">',
                                '<img alt="" height="60" width="40" src="'+src+'">',                                
                            '</div>',
                            '<div class="body">',
                                '<div class="time">',
                                    '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>',
                                    '<span class="blue">'+message_date+'</span>',
                                '</div>',

                                '<div class="name">',
                                    '<a href="#"></a>',
                                '</div>',
                                '<div class="'+message_class+'">'+message+'</div>',
                                '<div class="tools">',
                                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-minier btn-info">',
                                        '<i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-trash"></i>',
                                    '</a>',
                                '</div>',
                            '</div>',
                        '</div>'].join('\n');
                        //alert(messagehtml);
                        $("#message_wall").append(messagehtml);     
                }

            }

  //display number of messsage realtime
            function get_all_notif_message(){
                var number_of_messages=0;
                var message_from   ="{{$message_from}}";
                var message_to     ="{{$message_to}}";
                var message_url    ="{{url('messanger/realtime/message_notification')}}"+"/"+message_from+"/"+message_to;
                $.ajax({
                    url        :message_url,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    type       :"get",
                    async      :false,
                    success: function (response) {
                      var data=JSON.parse(response);
                      //$("#total_message").val(data.number_of_messages)
                      //alert(data.number_of_messages)
                      number_of_messages=data.number_of_messages;
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }


                });
                return number_of_messages;
            }

//function to handle DOM operatioin base on old number total  
function listen_crud(){                 
  var uptodate_message=get_all_notif_message();         
  $("#uptodate_massage").val(get_all_notif_message());          
  if($("#total_message").val() < uptodate_message){
  //alert("new message received")
`var audio = new Audio('{{url("assets/sound/inquisitiveness.mp3")}}');              
audio.play();           
$("#total_message").val(uptodate_message);              
refresh_messanger();
`var objDiv =` `document.getElementById("message_container");`                              
objDiv.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);                      
 }      
} 
//first program running
setInterval(listen_crud,5000);
```

https://pastebin.com/6rhpwCir
[HTML View related to .dialogdiv class"](https://pastebin.com/6rhpwCir)

send me your advice  please.

Comment: My suggestion is that your ajax request in function "get_all_notif_message"  is not synchronous. As your are doing, your code is waiting for the response. You should put the code to update the messenger inside the response function of the ajax call, or use a promise. I think that your performance would be better

Comment: @bandro, I can't return ajax response to function when set async =true

Comment: Fully agree with Bandro. You should **never** use `async: false` unless you really dislike the people using your application. But in this case you might want to consider using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). That way your server will notify the browser if a new message is available, so you don't have to wait 5 seconds before your message arrives.

Comment: @Alimin Indeed you can't. But you should call another function handling the response from your success callback.

Comment: @Ivar. if I using websocket technology. is posible to continue my coding above to combine between them.
at least I am using jquery bootstrap  to frontend also PHP laravel to handle API

Comment: @bandro .do you mean. I must do everything  when ajax sucess 
success: function (response){
//do all stuff about document object model, handle triger etc
}
honestly. I am woried my codding structure become so dirty if I do all stuff inside ajax sucess

Comment: @Alimin You should rework your code a bit to allow WebSockets but you can keep most of it. I don't really know Laravel, but it seems [it supports WebSockets as well](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting).

Comment: @Alimin And yes you should put it in the AJAX success, but you can also put it in a separate function and call that function from your success.

Comment: websocket or turn on my asyncronous with true. will spend my night today :D
I think it's oke for better performance
thank you.

Comment: If you want to do it like fb, or any "realtime" use websockets!

Answer (score 0):

@Alimin setting `async: false` causes it to **BLOCK** the input/ output. Meaning during the execution of the ajax, the whole browser will have to freeze until it return as response, either a success or error. You said that you don't want to do everything inside the success function - this is just structuring the code. A `$.ajax()` returns a promise. You can use `async/ await` and write it like synchronous code - more neat fashion.

To be honest, its bad design calling ajax every few seconds for "real time". What you can do is use websockets. Socket IO is an example. It's really simple and light. You can spin up a Node server to run Socket IO, and have your Laravel server separately.

It's as easiest as this:

Client Js - In Laravel

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io('localhost:3000'); // connect to socket io server
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val()); //replace with your msg input
      $('#m').val(''); //replace with your msg input
      return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      console.log(msg); //receive message from node js
     });

  });
</script>
```

Node Js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){ //listen for 'chat message' event
    io.emit('chat message', msg); //send data to clients
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

---

Updated 17/01/2019:

I've removed `async: false` so the browser doesn't hold. So to use the returned data from ajax request, use `async/ await`. It's much more neat.

```
//function to updating html element when new message comes (DOM operation)
function refresh_messanger(){

$(".dialogdiv").remove();
    var y=get_update_message_in_messanger();

    for(var i=0; i<= y.length-1; i++){
        var message=y[i].message_content;
        var message_date=y[i].message_date;
        var src="";
        if(y[i].photo_profile=='{{session("session_photo_profile")}}'){
            src="{{url('uploads/image').'/'.session('session_login')['app_user_id'].'/'.session('session_photo_profile')}}";
        }else{
            src="{{url('uploads/image')}}/"+y[i].message_from+'/'+y[i].photo_profile;
        }
        var message_class="";
        if(i==0){
            message_class="text-bold"
        }else{
            message_class="text";
        }
        var messagehtml=['<div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">',
                    '<div class="user">',
                        '<img alt="" height="60" width="40" src="'+src+'">',                                
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="body">',
                        '<div class="time">',
                            '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>',
                            '<span class="blue">'+message_date+'</span>',
                        '</div>',

                        '<div class="name">',
                            '<a href="#"></a>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="'+message_class+'">'+message+'</div>',
                        '<div class="tools">',
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-minier btn-info">',
                                '<i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-trash"></i>',
                            '</a>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>'].join('\n');
                //alert(messagehtml);
                $("#message_wall").append(messagehtml);     
    }

}

    //display number of messsage realtime
    async function get_all_notif_message(){
        var number_of_messages=0;
        var message_from   ="{{$message_from}}";
        var message_to     ="{{$message_to}}";
        var message_url    ="{{url('messanger/realtime/message_notification')}}"+"/"+message_from+"/"+message_to;

        let ajax_res;

        ajax_res = await $.ajax({
            url        :message_url,
            contentType:"application/json",
            type       :"get",    
        });

        let data = JSON.parse(ajax_res);
        return data.number_of_messages;
    }

    //function to handle DOM operatioin base on old number total  
    async function listen_crud(){ 
        let uptodate_message;


        try {
            uptodate_message= await get_all_notif_message();    
        } catch (error) {
            alert("Error");
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }                

        $("#uptodate_massage").val(uptodate_message);
        if($("#total_message").val() < uptodate_message){
            //alert("new message received")
            var audio = new Audio('{{url("assets/sound/inquisitiveness.mp3")}}');              
            audio.play();           
            $("#total_message").val(uptodate_message);              
            refresh_messanger();
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("message_container");                              
            objDiv.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);                      
        }      

        setTimeout(listen_crud, 5000);

    } 


    //first program running
    setTimeout(listen_crud, 5000);
```

---

**Resources:**

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: so what requirement I need. to doing your technique?
is this enough to adding 2 lines and getting started with socket IO.js and make simple real aplication with socket.io.js?
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

Comment: @Alimin Harus download Node js dulu bro. Terus bikin node server, install express dan socket io. 

Lalu di client JS laravel, include script client socket io nya:  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

Comment: Oke thank you, but I I think I just need to optimize my jquery realtime on my algorithm. not build codding base on scratch. My project using laravel layouting and I nearly finishing them.

Comment: the problem is after sending 5 or more messages, the application becomes slow and the browser too.
please read my post description carefuly to understand entire problem

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186833/discussion-between-alimin-and-adis).

Comment: How dis you go? @Alimin